# Host lookup that respects /etc/hosts

Tags: dns, hosts

Utilities like `host` and `dig` let you see the IP address corresponding to the host name.

There is also the `getent` utility that can be used to query `/etc/hosts` or other NSS databases.

I am looking for a convenient standard utility (which is available in Debian, say) which resolves a host name regardless of where it is defined.

It should be more or less equivalent to

```
ping "$HOST" | head -1 | perl -lne '/\((.*?)\)/ && print $1'
```

Comment: What exactly is wrong with `getent`?

Comment: Yeah, I don't thing it could get more convenient than getent.

Comment: @Patrick: hmm, I didn't realise `getent` also looks in DNS (I thought it only looks in `/etc/hosts`). Now that I've tried it, here's what's wrong with `getent`: for `google.com`, it returns a single address, and that address is IPv6. Which is not helpful, since I'm on an IPv4 network, and my command would actually print an IPv4 address.

Comment: @RomanCheplyaka - See eppesuig's answer that shows how to use getent to only look for IPv4 addresses: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/71392/7453

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only command that I am aware that does what you want is resolveip:

http://linux.die.net/man/1/resolveip

However it only comes with mysql-server, which may not be ideal to install everywhere.

Answer (score 17):

If the problem is that you do not want to resolve these names using ipv6, then just ask getent to use ipv4 only. This will enumerate all ipv4 addresses:

```
giuseppe@blatta:~$ getent ahostsv4 www.google.com | cut -d' ' -f1 | sort -u
173.194.40.80
173.194.40.81
173.194.40.82
173.194.40.83
173.194.40.84
```

Comment: For those who do care to forget history (i.e. IPv4), use `ahostsv6`.

Comment: For those who want to avoid considering the differences between IPv4 and IPv6, use `getent ahosts google.com`.

Answer (score 5):

The thing is there are several APIs to resolve host names like `gethostbyname`, `getaddrinfo` and `inet_pton` and some of those can return more than one address and/or you can query the type of address you want.

If you want a portable way to get *one* IPv4 address, then maybe:

```
perl -MSocket -le 'print inet_ntoa inet_aton shift' www.google.com
```

Answer (score 3):

`gethostip -d name.domain` from the `syslinux` package on Ubuntu (and probably Debian). `-d` outputs decimal format.

Answer (score 1):

(This answer only applies if you're root on the machine.)

I used to be annoyed by this too, and then I standardized on running [dnsmasq](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dnsmasq) on all my machines. Dnsmasq is a lightweight DNS cache. As a side benefit, it serves the content of `/etc/hosts` over DNS.

Answer (score 1):

I used my poor perl knowledge and made a little script with error handling:

/usr/local/bin/gethostip:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# inspired by: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71379/host-lookup-that-respects-etc-hosts#71393

use strict;
use Socket;

my $name = $ARGV[0];
if ($name eq '') {
  print STDERR "Usage: gethostip <hostname>\n";
  exit 1;
}
my $ip = inet_aton($name);
die("Unable to resolve host name $name") if ($ip eq '');
my $ipstr = inet_ntoa($ip);
print "$ipstr\n";
```

Thx to Stéphane Chazelas for the initial idea